# Get swagger to authenticate with Azure AD + spring boot configuration

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I have a spring boot REST service which is protected with Azure AD, so I'm using the Spring Boot Starter for Azure AD.

I'm also using the springdoc-openapi library to generate the API documentation. For now I'm hand writing the yaml file to describe the documentation.

I'm looking for help with getting swagger to authenticate with Azure AD so that I can try out the endpoints in the backend.

Is there someway to do this by either editing the yaml file or with the springdoc-openapi library?

Answer (score -1):

For getting swagger to authenticate with Azure AD you need to create registered two web application one is for webAPI and another is for your swagger.Then you shoukd require Delegated Permissions for your Swagger Web Site to ‘Access’ your WebAPI.As swagger is in-built configured in the .Net 5.0 template so that we don't need to take care of documenting our APIs in this latest .Net 5.0.

You can refer this [***Document***](https://skycliffs.com/2017/11/09/enable-swagger-to-authenticate-against-azure-ad-revised/comment-page-1/) here they have given in steps how to authenticate swagger with azuread.

You can also refer this [***document***](https://developers.de/blogs/armin_kalajdzija/archive/2016/11/23/setup-swagger-to-authenticate-against-azure-active-directory.aspx) for **how**  **Setup Swagger to authenticate against Azure Active Directory** is provided by devloper community of `.net`

Comment: OP asked specifically about Spring Boot which is a Java library.   Your answers are for .net and do not answer any part of the question.